In saying "how things ought to be how they ought to be..." is the use of "ought to be" redundant?
Below is a quote from Herbert Simon (italics his, not mine)-
"...the designer, is concerned with how things ought to be how they ought to be in order to attain goals, and to function."
How is it different if I simply say that the designer is concerned with how things ought to be in order to attain goals and to function.

You should post a full reference to the source. It seems like you're reading a defective copy. I don't know if you're embarrassed because your version is pirated, which would explain both the error and your reluctance to explain where you saw it.

I’m voting to close this question because the OP seems to be cited an incorrectly punctuated edition of perfectly ordinary text.

'... concerned with how things ought to be how they ought to be in order to [achieve]' is clunky, but makes sense: '... concerned with how things ought to be in what is considered the optimal state in order to [achieve]'. I'd prefer a comma after 'state', and the whole sentence might be seen as a platitude. // But this is a misquote at some level; the original contains an expansion on 'how things ought to be', qualifying the statement and repeating the string for emphasis.

The full quote is this:

The engineer, and more generally the designer, is concerned with how things ought to be - how they ought to be in order to attain goals, and to function.

I don't see any problem with the above quote.
The dash (which you've omitted in your post) indicates a brief pause. The writer takes on the preceding statement further after the dash and completes it after adding extra information.

There is no dash in the version I am reading.

Obviously an OCR failure on the version you picked. I had no problem finding several correctly scanned versions.
